# Generate the message in case of empty data

Tags: vb.net, desktop-application, ado.net-entity-data-model

I have a Query about a vb.net code.
I am using ADO.NET Entity Framework Data Model with a desktop app.

MY functionality is right now.
When I find a data from the database it generates a message as you can see in the code.

MY question is
How can i generate a message when there is no matching data in DB?

```
 Private Sub btnSearch_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnSearch.Click
        Using db As SMSTEntities = New SMSTEntities()
            Try
                Dim Query = From PhoneNumber In db.PhoneNumberOfCustomers
                            Where PhoneNumber.PhoneNumber.Equals(txtNumber.Text) Select PhoneNumber


                For Each phoneNumber In Query
                    MessageBox.Show("Your Searched Data " + txtNumber.Text + " Is Present in Database, Please Insert the Releated Information")
                Next
            Catch ex As Exception
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
            End Try
        End Using

    End Sub
```

How can i use if else statement in this case.
Any help is welcome.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: If Query.Any() Then MessageBox.Show("Your Message") End If

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @N0Alias 
I just exchange the For Each loop with 
if statement with Query.Any() method.

```
Private Sub btnSearch_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnSearch.Click
        Using db As SMSTEntities = New SMSTEntities()
            Try
                Dim Query = From PhoneNumber In db.PhoneNumberOfCustomers
                            Where PhoneNumber.PhoneNumber.Equals(txtNumber.Text) Select PhoneNumber


                If Query.Any() Then


                    MessageBox.Show("Your Searched Data " + txtNumber.Text + " Is Present in Database, Please Insert the Releated Information")
                Else
                    MessageBox.Show("Your Searched Data " + txtNumber.Text + " Is Not Present in Database")
                End If
            Catch ex As Exception
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
            End Try
        End Using

    End Sub
```